# How to make Pie chart in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, graph, charts

I am trying to make a pie chart based on the value of variables in the controller plz suggest easiest way to implement this.

Comment: try d3.js, https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/jDvdSh

Comment: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ here you find perfect example

Comment: [angular.piechart](https://github.com/jcubic/angular.piechart) and [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/xRMGZz)

Answer (score 5):

You can use

1) [Angular chart (using Chart.js)](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)

2) [angular directives for commonly used d3 charts](http://chinmaymk.github.io/angular-charts/)

3) [AngularJS Directive](https://www.fusioncharts.com/angularjs-charts/)

4) [An AngularJS directive for NVD3 re-usable charting library (based on D3).](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/)

5) [Google Charts also use with AngularJS](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

I hope this will help you...

Answer (score 2):

I hope this answer will help you. Using Angular charts you can make a pie chart or any other chart

1. [Angular Chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)

   ```
    npm install angular-chart.js --save
   ```

It requires only 2 dependencies **angularjs and chartjs**

2. [Angular nvD3 chart](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/)

   ```
     { "chart": {
       "type": "pieChart",
       "height": 500,
       "showLabels": true,
       "duration": 500,
       "labelThreshold": 0.01,
       "labelSunbeamLayout": true,
       "legend": {
         "margin": {
            "top": 5,
            "right": 35,
            "bottom": 5,
            "left": 0
     }
   }
   ```

   }
   }

Answer (score 1):

You can use Highchart API with angular js
**https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts**

You can use alos Highchart without angular js to draw Pie chart ->

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

 <script>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
},
title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            style: {
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            }
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 61.41,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
    }, {
        name: 'Internet Explorer',
        y: 11.84
    }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 10.85
    }, {
        name: 'Edge',
        y: 4.67
    }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        y: 4.18
    }, {
        name: 'Sogou Explorer',
        y: 1.64
    }, {
        name: 'Opera',
        y: 1.6
    }, {
        name: 'QQ',
        y: 1.2
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        y: 2.61
    }]
}]
});
```